# Is there a way to make this CSS more concise?

Tags: css

The following CSS seems to be doing what I want. Just wondering if it could be trimmed and still do the same thing.

```
.qr-setup {
  text-align: center  ;
  margin-left: auto  ;
  margin-right: auto  ; 
  width:40%  ;}

.qr-setup table {
  text-align: center  ;
  margin-left: auto  ;
  margin-right: auto  ; 
  width:80%  ;
}

.qr-setup table tr td {
  border: none;
  text-align: center  ;
  margin-left: auto  ;
  margin-right: auto  ; 
  width:80%  ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.qr-setup, .qr-setup table, .qr-setup tr td {
  text-align: center  ;
  margin-left: auto  ;
  margin-right: auto  ; 
  width: 80%;}

.qr-setup {
  width:40%  ;
}

.qr-setup table tr td {
 border: none;
```

}

Comment: @user1147171 FYI, unless these tables are getting a margin from somewhere else, you don't need the `margin: auto` as it's defaulted to auto.

Comment: Thanks, everyone!  @Leeish, a good point to remember. In this case, the margins are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You only need this:

```
.qr-setup {
    width:40%;
}

.qr-setup table, .qr-setup table tr td {
    width:80%;
}

.qr-setup table tr td {
    border: none;
}

.qr-setup, .qr-setup table, .qr-setup table tr td {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

You can use commas to repeat the css for all that's listed.

Comment: I think he still needs the width on the td as width is not inherited.

Answer (score 0):

There's even a shorthand for

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

namely

```
margin:0 auto;
```

This code sets margin-top and margin-bottom to 0 and margin-left and margin-right to auto.